# Combining Items in a JSON object by adding up values of all unique keys and covert to a delimited string

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I've a JSON or Javascript structure like this
var myJSON=

```
{
   "A":{
      "59":"13",
      "60":"13",
      "61":"26",
      "62":"10",
      "63":"16",
      "64":"19",
      "65":"8",
      "66":"9"
   },
   "B":{
      "59":"11",
      "60":"13",
      "61":"22",
      "62":"8",
      "63":"8",
      "64":"7",
      "65":"21",
      "66":"14"
   },
   "C":{
      "59":"5",
      "61":"0",
      "62":"4",
      "63":"4",
      "65":"4"
   }
}
```

But I need to build another object from the same structure using the values of each of the keys under each of the main elements
[image]

So the output is like a delimitted string combining all the unique keys of the above JSON. 
Result will be like this

**`59:29#60:26#61:48#62:22#63:28#64:26#65:33#66:23`**

All the keys from the structure has to be in the delimited string. As I highlighted in the image for **59** it added the values of all **59**

Comment: Didn't you want to add the tag `javascript`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var myJSON = {
    "A": { "59": "13", "60": "13", "61": "26", "62": "10", "63": "16", "64": "19", "65": "8", "66": "9" },
    "B": { "59": "11", "60": "13", "61": "22", "62": "8", "63": "8", "64": "7", "65": "21", "66": "14" },
    "C": { "59": "5", "61": "0", "62": "4", "63": "4", "65": "4" }
}

var consolidatedObject = {};
// loop through the top level properties
for (var a in myJSON) {
    if (myJSON.hasOwnProperty(a)) {
        // add the keys and the values
        for (var b in myJSON[a])
            if (myJSON[a].hasOwnProperty(b)) {
                consolidatedObject[b] = (consolidatedObject[b] | 0) + Number(myJSON[a][b]);
            }
    }
}

// beat into shape
console.log(JSON.stringify(consolidatedObject).replace(/"/g, '').replace(/,/g, '#').replace(/[{}]/g, ''));
```

```js
var myJSON = {
  "A": { "59": "13", "60": "13", "61": "26", "62": "10", "63": "16", "64": "19", "65": "8", "66": "9" },
  "B": { "59": "11", "60": "13", "61": "22", "62": "8", "63": "8", "64": "7", "65": "21", "66": "14" },
  "C": { "59": "5", "61": "0", "62": "4", "63": "4", "65": "4" }
}

var consolidatedObject = {};
// loop through the top level properties
for (var a in myJSON) {
  if (myJSON.hasOwnProperty(a)) {
    // add the keys and the values
    for (var b in myJSON[a])
      if (myJSON[a].hasOwnProperty(b)) {
        consolidatedObject[b] = (consolidatedObject[b] | 0) + Number(myJSON[a][b]);
      }
  }
}

// beat into shape
alert(JSON.stringify(consolidatedObject).replace(/"/g, '').replace(/,/g, '#').replace(/[{}]/g, ''));
```

Comment: Waw.. Thanks a lot boss!! made my day

Answer (score 1):

**UPD**. Actually my previous solution is stupid, overcomplecated for no reason. Here is much better:

```js
var data = {
    "A":{"59":"13","60":"13","61":"26","62":"10","63":"16","64":"19","65":"8","66":"9"},
    "B":{"59":"11","60":"13","61":"22","62":"8","63":"8","64":"7","65":"21","66":"14"},
    "C":{"59":"5","61":"0","62":"4","63":"4","65":"4"}
};

var result = {};

for (var key in data) {
  for (var subkey in data[key]) {
    result[subkey] = (result[subkey] || 0) + Number(data[key][subkey]);
  }
}

result = Object.keys(result).map(function(key) {
    return key + ':' + result[key];
}).join('#');

alert(result);
```

**Bad solution.** <strike>You can use couple of for-loops and map. Or you can go with atomic Object.keys+reduce+forEach combination:</strike>

```js
var data = {
    "A":{"59":"13","60":"13","61":"26","62":"10","63":"16","64":"19","65":"8","66":"9"},
    "B":{"59":"11","60":"13","61":"22","62":"8","63":"8","64":"7","65":"21","66":"14"},
    "C":{"59":"5","61":"0","62":"4","63":"4","65":"4"}
};

var result = Object.keys(data).reduce(function(prev, key) {
    Object.keys(data[key]).forEach(function(k) {
        if (!prev[k]) prev[k] = 0;
        prev[k] += +data[key][k]; 
    });
    return prev;
}, {});

result = Object.keys(result).map(function(key) {
    return key + ':' + result[key];
}).join('#');

alert(result);
```